# Using Firebase, how can I remove duplicate results from a query?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My eventual plan is to create an accordion list where food names are displayed by clicking the corresponding category. However, right now I need to not display duplicate categories like "Dairy". How can I do this?

I have the following database structure in Firebase:

```
{
  "aePQkvozV6gehP7ihjN0OWCltKu2" : {
    "-Kv4xipPl0_2oztTMhaS" : {
      "category" : "Dairy",
      "foodname" : "Milk",
      "state" : "on"
    },
    "-Kv4xipRPvW5ejLTtosX" : {
      "category" : "Dairy",
      "foodname" : "Butter",
      "state" : "on"
    },
    "-Kv4xipS3lNBqYzknNhL" : {
      "category" : "Meat",
      "foodname" : "Chicken",
      "state" : "on"
    },
    "-Kv4xipTchrGh8D_lGmR" : {
      "category" : "Produce",
      "foodname" : "Strawberries",
      "state" : "on"
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following query:

```
getUserList(user): FirebaseListObservable<any> {

  console.log('firebase.auth().currentUser', user);

  return this.db.list('userlist' + '/' + user.uid, {
      query: {
        orderByChild:'category'
      }
    });
  }
```

Category is being displayed by the following HTML:

```
<ion-item id="foodnames" *ngFor="let list of lists" (click)="additem(item)">
    {{list.category}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to firebase, but I don't believe it has a way to pull unique values out of a list of objects. You could add an rxjs .map() function to the end of your observable to filter out the categories

Comment: where do you want to remove the duplicates from? After getting a list from an api call? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

in this case I guess You should Edit your database structure
to be Like

```
{
  "Dairy":
  {
  "aePQkvozV6gehP7ihjN0OWCltKu2" : {
    "-Kv4xipPl0_2oztTMhaS" : {
       "foodname" : "Milk",
      "state" : "on"
    },
    "-Kv4xipRPvW5ejLTtosX" : {
       "foodname" : "Butter",
      "state" : "on"
    }}
    "Meat":{
    "-Kv4xipS3lNBqYzknNhL" : {
       "foodname" : "Chicken",
      "state" : "on"
    }}
}
```

Now You can Get Only Specific  category